# Necessary and sufficient condition of $f$ satisfying $f(E[X]) - E[f(X)] > 0$

Tags: inequality, expectation

I am trying to looking into function $f$ which satisfies the inequality $f(E[X]) - E[f(X)] > 0$ where $E[X]$ is the expectation of positive random variable $X$.

My questions is, what is the necessary and sufficient condition of $f$ satisfying the inequality?

Guess and Attempt:

Do not know how to attack the problem rigorously.

I have tried a case that $f(x) = \ln(x)$, and I found that the inequality $f(E[X]) - E[f(X)] > 0$ is exactly A.M. > G.M..

For $f(x) = x^n$ with $n > 1$,
$f(E[X]) - E[f(X)] = (E[X])^n - (M_n[X])^n < 0$ because it is the difference between generalized mean $M_n$ and mean $E$, both to the power $n$.

For $f(x) = x$ the equality holds obviously.

So I guess that $f(x) < x$ for positive $x$ is the required necessary and sufficient condition.

Comment: Hint: Consider a random variable $X$ which can take only two values. Are you familiar with the definition of a [convex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function)?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Knowing the famous Jensen's theorem, my question reduces to $f(E(X)) > E(f(X))$ iff f is convex. By your hint I successfully prove the only-if statement by induction. But how can I prove the if statement starting from scratch?